# React Native Android - "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly"

Tags: react-native

Running on Android - I can no longer get my app to build. I've tried 15+ ideas on stack overflow with similar batchedbridge errors'.

Results - after packaging:
- Red error screen popups up with "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged properly” (with no other callstack details) and then a second later get a blank white screen.

Results - after the error and then reloading from the app dev tools menu:
- Could not connect to development server

- react-native version 0.40.0 npm=5.0.3 node=v7.4.0
- The app was working previously for months so i'm guessing connected to a recent change, version problem, cache problem, npm version or reactnative version?
- Tried adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
- Tried npm cache clean
- Tried on emulator and device - same issue
- Tried closing all react packagers
- Made sure no other react native apps/packagers running
- Android app is building OK in Android Studio (without react native)

Looking in the logcat I seem some red flags but not sure if these problems are new or were previously there:
- Lots of 'ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.???????' etc
- React: The packager does not seem to be running as we got an IOException requesting its status: Connection reset

Here's the logcat snippet and stack trace from the app when it tries to start - if you need more of the logcat let me know (my attempt to add it here didn't work).

```
iceapp.challengeme ic=null D/FA: Connected to remote service W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2 W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSendButtonManager W/art: Before Android 4.1, method boolean com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButtonBase.canShare() would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.TextView W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBShareButtonManager 

    E/unknown:React: Exception in native call from JS
                     com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                      Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)  W/unknown:React: Packager connection already open, nooping. W/unknown:React: Inspector connection already open, nooping. E/unknown:React: Exception in native call
                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling function: RCTDeviceEventEmitter:emit
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Empty Optional cannot be unwrapped
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)  E/unknown:React: Exception in native call
                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling function: AppRegistry:runApplication
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Empty Optional cannot be unwrapped
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: More info - note I have other react native projects running fine using the same setup and device/emulator.

Comment: did you try `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install`?

Comment: Thanks @Raymond... no luck on that though